# Is it possible to run subquery as islolated query only once?

Tags: mysql

I have a users table with a single index on each of the following columns `first_name`, `last_name` and `company_id`.

Running this query.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    (`first_name` LIKE 'bill%'
        OR `last_name` LIKE 'bill%' 
OR company_id in (100))
```

uses all indexes as expected:

[image]

However, running this modified query, does not use any of the indexes:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    (`first_name` LIKE 'bill%'
        OR `last_name` LIKE 'bill%' Or company_id in ( 
       SELECT 
           `id`
       FROM
          `companies`
       WHERE
            `name` LIKE 'bill%'
 ) )
```

[image]

Instead, it iterates over all user records and for each it executed the sub-query.

This makes me wonder, is it possible to tell SQL to execute the subquery

```
SELECT 
    `id`
FROM
    `companies`
WHERE
    `name` LIKE 'bill%'
```

only once independently and not for each single query again?

---

Edit: This is with JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    *
 FROM
    `users`
        INNER JOIN
    `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `users`.`company_id`
WHERE
    (`first_name` LIKE 'bill%'
        OR `last_name` LIKE 'bill%' 
        OR `companies`.`name` LIKE 'bill%')
```

Its much slower and no index is used on users table, also I have indexed (id,name) on `companies` and in addition (company_id, first_name) aswell as (comapny_id,last_name):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a join?

Comment: @mustaccio yes I have tried to use a join and a tuplie index (id, name) on the company, but the query ended up beeing 400ms, where if I the there WHERE IN, the whole query reduces to 2ms. However, I have to do 2 seperate queries, now I wonder if I can do it in one.

Comment: Have you tried using a Refactored Subquery? (CTE, `WITH` clause)

Comment: @MichaelKutz - "subquery refactoring" is Oracle-speak - **everyone** else calls them CTEs! :-)

Comment: @mustaccio I edited my join approach to the question - as you can see it uses no indexes on the users table thats probably why its so slow

Comment: @MichaelKutz how would that work in this case? I just looked CTE up and tried this: `WITH special_companies AS ( SELECT id FROM companies WHERE name LIKE 'bill%') SELECT 
    * FROM users WHERE (first_name LIKE 'bill%' OR last_name LIKE 'bill%' OR company_id = special_companies)` but I get `unknown column special_companies.id`

Comment: Can you set something up on DB Fiddle? (At least the `CREATE TABLE` statements.) As noted by Verace, I'm more familiar with Oracle. I'd want to make sure the code works for your RDBMS before I write an answer.

Comment: Most cases of `OR` can be optimized by using `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic solution: `OR` --> `UNION`:

```
( SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE 'bill%' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE 'bill%' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id in (100) )
```

with a [potentially] different index designed for each `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(first_name),
INDEX(last_name),
INDEX(company_id)
```

None of these are useful for performance:  `JOIN`, `CTE`, `WITH`, `LEFT JOIN`, subquery, derived table

Comment: I think whenever I have an `and` condition, `JOIN` works well for me in terms of performance. I guess the last sentence of your post is only in the scenario of `or` condition's containing both tables?

Comment: @Adam - `AND` can be optimized in many situations, especially when the ANDs refer to a single table.  When `AND` is used across two tables (and a `JOIN`), the Optimizer will decide which table to start with, it might be able to use the conditions in both table lookups.  It depends.  `OR` is rarely optimizable.  (Looking at specific examples may be instructive.)  See also: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql